# jsii-pacmak ignores dist-* files from @aws-sdk/util-utf8-browser

Tags: typescript, aws-sdk, aws-cdk, jsii

I have a monorepo of CDK patterns which I build and package using jsii and jsii-pacmak respectively. I need to use few AWS-SDK modules in one of the patterns so I have bundled the following:

```
"bundledDependencies": [
"@aws-sdk/client-ec2",
"@aws-sdk/client-codestar-connections",
"@aws-sdk/client-sts"
],
```

I use nohoist in my package.json to ensure these are installed in the node_modules of the required patterns. When I install the dependencies and build the packages I see the following in node_modules:

[image]

The three dist- files inside @aws-sdk/util-utf8-browser is the concern which are there in my local. But after I run jsii-pacmak I don't see those three dist- files. I extracted the JS tarball and found them missing. However other util-* modules are not impacted.

[image]

Due to these missing files, I get the following error when I run cdk synth/deploy:

```
Error: Cannot find module '<my-project-dir>node_modules/cdk/node_modules/@aws-sdk/util-utf8-browser/dist-cjs/index.js'. 
Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
```

Because the main entry is of course in the `"main": "./dist-cjs/index.js"`, while it is missing from the JS distribution after running jsii-pacmak.

Complete error stack:

```
lalitkumarb@host cdk-patterns % cdk synth
Error: Cannot find module 'packages/cdk-patterns/node_modules/my-cdk/node_modules/@aws-sdk/util-utf8-browser/dist-cjs/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:353:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:566:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (my-cdk/node_modules/@cspotcode/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:811:30)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (packages/cdk-patterns/node_modules/my-cdk/node_modules/@aws-crypto/util/src/convertToBuffer.ts:5:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'packages/cdk-patterns/node_modules/my-cdk/node_modules/@aws-sdk/util-utf8-browser/package.json',
  requestPath: '@aws-sdk/util-utf8-browser'
}

Subprocess exited with error 1
```

I am not sure whether it's a bug or I am doing something wrong. For what it's worth, I have also opened a GitHub issue on JSII repo https://github.com/aws/jsii/issues/4178 which has the steps to reproduce the issue. If I could somehow manage to package the three missing dist-* files from `@aws-sdk/util-utf8-browser` the issue would be resolved.

CDK and SDK version used

```
cdk - 2.81.0 (build bd920f2), @aws-sdk "version": "3.363.0"
```

Environment details (OS name and version, etc.)

```
Mac OS Ventura 13.4, Ubuntu 20.04, 22.04 and @latest.
```

**Reproduction steps:**

I have created following public repo for reproducing the issue quickly: https://github.com/lalitkumarbTR/jsii-pacmak-issue Please follow the steps mentioned in the README.

Update: It works on Amazon Linux and Ubuntu 18.04 when tested on AWS Cloud9 running on EC2. Unfortunately, GitHub runner cannot run neither Amazon Linux nor Ubuntu 18.04(deprecated). I cannot use self-hosted runner just for packaging the artifacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sharing the workaround as an answer here so it could help anyone facing similar issue.

**Workaround**: Use node `v18.13`

**More details:**

I opened a case with AWS and the support engineer was able to figure out the workaround. The reason it worked on Amazon Linux and not on Ubuntu 20.04/22.04 is because of the node version which is 18.13 on AL2023 while it is 18.17 by default from nvm on Ubuntu. On my laptop MacOS I was running node v16.x and it did not work either, so upgrading to node 18.13 fixed the issue. The active support for node 18(LTS) will end on (18 Oct 2023) per https://endoflife.date/nodejs So it would be better to get this issue/bug fixed on all node versions > 18.

Comment: made my day! I'd never thought pinning to another minor version, in my case, would fix the issue. Thanks a lot!